# Run all tasks in playbook with_items

Tags: ansible

I want the playbook to run once with each item in the list and not all items in the list at once.

Ansible version: 2.6.1

`Tasks.yaml`:

```
 ---

- name: Task 1
  debug:
    msg: "Message 1: {{ item }}"
  with_items: "{{ messages }}"

- name: Task 2
  debug:
    msg: "Message 2: {{ item }}"
  with_items: "{{ messages }}"
```

Playbook:

```
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: no
  tasks:
  - import_tasks: Tasks.yml
    vars:
      messages:
        - 1
        - 2
```

This is my expected result:

```
Task 1 with Item 1
Task 2 with Item 1
Task 3 with Item 1
Task 1 with Item 2
Task 2 with Item 2
Task 3 with Item 2
Task 1 with Item 3
Task 2 with Item 3
Task 3 with Item 3
```

But when I execute the playbook, then it is like this:

```
Task 1 with Item 1
Task 1 with Item 2
Task 2 with Item 1
Task 2 with Item 2
Task 3 with Item 1
Task 3 with Item 2
...
```

I tried both import and include - both have the same result.

Comment: ? I do not know, what you mean... ;)

Comment: Hmm. I thought I only added the two tags "ansible" and "playbook".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `playbook.yml` should implement a loop (notice you cannot loop with `import_tasks`; it will raise an error):

```
- hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  gather_facts: no

  vars:
    messages:
      - 1
      - 2
      - 3

  tasks:
    - include_tasks: Tasks.yml
      loop: "{{ messages }}"
```

And `Tasks.yml` should look like this (no loops inside):

```
---
- name: Task 1
  debug:
    msg: "Message 1: {{ item }}"

- name: Task 2
  debug:
    msg: "Message 2: {{ item }}"
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I will check that.

Comment: Note that if you have an inside "with_items" you need to save the outer var like in https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.3/playbooks_loops.html#loops-and-includes-in-2-0 and if you want to avoid the warning about "item" already in use you must  use loop_control:
    loop_var: item_foo
to redeclare the item var